# How to set width base on characters

Tags: css

I want to set the width of a paragraph base on its character count. For that I am using the the `ch` unit. The problems is when I change the font-family, for it seems that the `ch` unit used a monospace base.

Is there a way (with only CSS/HTML) to set a character-base width *regardless* of the (that works on *every*) font family?

Comment: No, since different fonts have different width for different characters. For example, here are eight i chars using the SO default font: iiiiiii and here are eight i's in monospace font: `iiiiiiii` (both are `font-size: 13px`)

Comment: I know that. So, let me refrain the question. Is there a way css can now the actual character count on a specific line?

Comment: You cannot set a width of an element based on it's number of characters within it, for 2 main reasons. First: different characters have different rendered width. Second: CSS works the other way around. You can set the child element based on it's parent, and not the parent based on its child.

Comment: The `ch` unit is the width of `0` (zero) character in the particular font. What are you trying to do?

Comment: My guess is that he want to build a dynamic width container that will grow and shrink as the contained text inside it changes...

Comment: @Narxx But the width of an element (parent) can be set base on its content (child). The `ch` unit does precisely that.

Comment: @Vorgan `ch` (and `em` and others') size is not based on content, but on (specified or inherited) `font-*` CSS rules.

Comment: @helb Oh! Great replay.

Comment: The problem is that I am working with an ePub, so I have no saying in the font-family the user chooses. And I need some lines to be a specific characters long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about CSS solution but,

You can do such thing using JavaScript, but it's not very convenient.

**Demo here:** https://jsbin.com/fecevopara/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Try to change text in html to see how width changes.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container')

const textLength = container.innerText.length

if (textLength > 10) {
  container.style.width = '50px'
}
if (textLength > 20) {
  container.style.width = '100px'
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" style="display: inline-block; width: 10px; background: #ccc">
   Some text goes hereeeee
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code (just example idea, not production ready at all):

```
const container = document.getElementById('container')

const textLength = container.innerText.length

if (textLength > 10) {
  container.style.width = '50px'
}
if (textLength > 20) {
  container.style.width = '100px'
}
```

and HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="container" style="display: inline-block; width: 10px; background: #ccc">
   Some text goes hereee
</div>
```

Basically it will dynamically change width style property of container depending on number of characters inside.